How to handle google consent page when scrapping article data using google news RSS links?
I have a list of google news links from google RSS feed and I would like to get full text of those articles. I use BeautifulSoup library to scrape the data, however, it seems that google redirects to the cookie consent page first. What is the best way to handle the consent step? Is there a way to bypass the consent page or programmatically accept/reject?
The below example returns the text from the consent page rather than the article text.
# Import libraries 
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

google_rss_url = 'https://news.google.com/rss/articles/CBMimwFBVV95cUxNVmJMNUdiamVCNkJSb1E4NVU0SlBFQUNneXpEaHFuRUJpN3lwRXFNNGdRalpITmFUQUh4Z3lsOVZ4ekFSdWVwVEljVUJOT241S1g2dmRmd3NnRmJjamU4TVFFdUVXd0N2MGVPTUdxb0RVZ2xQbUlkS1Y3eEhKbmdBN2hSUHNzS2ZucjlKQl84SW13ZVpXYlZXRnRSZw?oc=5'


# Send a GET request to the URL
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
response = requests.get(google_rss_url, headers=headers)

# Parse the response content with BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

# Find the main content of the article 
paragraphs = soup.find_all('p')

# Join the text from all paragraphs
article_text = '\n'.join([para.get_text() for para in paragraphs])


What is this "cookie consent page"? the url will redirect to this page, which uses javascript to redirect to the actual article, there is no consent page.

This is the link to the google consent page: https://consent.google.com/m?continue=https://news.google.com/rss/articles/CBMimwFBVV95cUxNVmJMNUdiamVCNkJSb1E4NVU0SlBFQUNneXpEaHFuRUJpN3lwRXFNNGdRalpITmFUQUh4Z3lsOVZ4ekFSdWVwVEljVUJOT241S1g2dmRmd3NnRmJjamU4TVFFdUVXd0N2MGVPTUdxb0RVZ2xQbUlkS1Y3eEhKbmdBN2hSUHNzS2ZucjlKQl84SW13ZVpXYlZXRnRSZw?oc%3D5&gl=LT&m=0&pc=n&cm=2&hl=en-US&src=1

are you getting that from response.url after  requests.get(google_rss_url)? I don't get the consent page neither with requests nor in the browser. You can bypass it by using the link after continue=, but it's strange that you get that, are you perhaps using a proxy/vpn?

I tried using the link after 'consent.google.com/m?continue=' but it took me to the same google consent page. I am able to replicate this issue manually by using Chrome incognito window (after clearing browsing history first). If I paste google_rss_url  example that I shared it redirects me to the consent page.
I am using my work laptop. It believe it doesn't use proxy or vpn but it might have some other setting that perhaps impact the behaviour of online browsers.

I still can't replicate the consent page issue, even with incognito/vpn/different browser. But even if you bypassed the consent page, you'll get a redirect page that requires javascript execution.
Here's how to bypass all of that and get the final article url:
import requests
from urllib.parse import urlencode, urlparse
import json

google_rss_url = 'https://news.google.com/rss/articles/CBMimwFBVV95cUxNVmJMNUdiamVCNkJSb1E4NVU0SlBFQUNneXpEaHFuRUJpN3lwRXFNNGdRalpITmFUQUh4Z3lsOVZ4ekFSdWVwVEljVUJOT241S1g2dmRmd3NnRmJjamU4TVFFdUVXd0N2MGVPTUdxb0RVZ2xQbUlkS1Y3eEhKbmdBN2hSUHNzS2ZucjlKQl84SW13ZVpXYlZXRnRSZw?oc=5'

# parse guid from url, or directly get it from rss <guid>
guid = urlparse(google_rss_url).path.replace('/rss/articles/', '')

param = '["garturlreq",[["en-US","US",["FINANCE_TOP_INDICES","WEB_TEST_1_0_0"],null,null,1,1,"US:en",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,0,5],"en-US","US",true,[2,4,8],1,true,"661099999",0,0,null,0],{guid}]'
payload = urlencode({
    'f.req': [[['Fbv4je', param.format(guid=guid), 'null', 'generic']]]
})

headers = {
  'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}

url = "https://news.google.com/_/DotsSplashUi/data/batchexecute"
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)

array_string = json.loads(response.text.replace(")]}'", ""))[0][2]
article_url = json.loads(array_string)[1]

print(article_url)


The best solution I have managed to find so far was to use Selenium library to accept cookies, wait to get redirected to the source website and extract sour e url. Then use newspaper library to extract article content. My code below.
# Import libraries
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from newspaper import Article, Config

# Set up driver
# Path to your ChromeDriver
driver_path = 'C:\\WebDrivers\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver.exe'

# Set up Chrome options
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")  # Run in headless mode

# Initialize the WebDriver
service = Service(driver_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

# Get source url 
google_rss_url = 'https://news.google.com/rss/articles/CBMimwFBVV95cUxNVmJMNUdiamVCNkJSb1E4NVU0SlBFQUNneXpEaHFuRUJpN3lwRXFNNGdRalpITmFUQUh4Z3lsOVZ4ekFSdWVwVEljVUJOT241S1g2dmRmd3NnRmJjamU4TVFFdUVXd0N2MGVPTUdxb0RVZ2xQbUlkS1Y3eEhKbmdBN2hSUHNzS2ZucjlKQl84SW13ZVpXYlZXRnRSZw?oc=5'
max_wait_time = 5

page_data = dict()
    
try:
    # Open the URL
    driver.get(google_rss_url)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, max_wait_time)
    
    # Check if the current URL is the consent page
    current_url = driver.current_url
    # print(f'Current url: {current_url}')
    if current_url.startswith("https://consent.google.com/"):
        print('Accepting cookie consent')
        try:        
            # Wait for the "Accept All" button to be clickable and click it
            accept_all_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[.//span[text()="Accept all"]]')))
            if accept_all_button:
                accept_all_button.click()
                print('Accept All button clicked')
        except:
            print('No Accept All button found')        

    # Wait until the URL changes to something that does not start with "https://news.google.com/"
    print("Redirecting to source website")
    wait.until(lambda driver: not driver.current_url.startswith("https://news.google.com/")
                                and not driver.current_url.startswith("https://consent.google.com/"))

    # Wait for the article page to be fully loaded 
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'body')))

    # Get page URL
    page_data['source_url'] = driver.current_url

except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred getting source url for {google_rss_url}: {e}")

driver.quit()  

# Print source url
print(page_data['source_url'])

# Get article content using newpaper3k library
# Url
url = page_data['source_url']

# Cofig user agent
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'
config = Config()
config.browser_user_agent = user_agent

article_data = dict()

try:
    # Use newspaper3k to download and parse the article
    article = Article(url, config=config)
    article.download()
    article.parse()

    # Save data
    article_data['article_title'] = article.title
    article_data['article_text'] = article.text

except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error extracting article from {url}: {e}")    

# Check output
article_data

Let me know if anyone finds a more straightforward solution.
